# Experimental 'Self modifying' programming

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Does anyone know of a project that uses some sort of interpreted runtime, to perhaps, as an example will take a before and after text file and generate and run a program in its-self to produce the after result. So it combines a bit of lexing, fuzzy logic, NN, backtracking, genetic programing, software FPGA.

I am interested in how the horsepower of modern quad socket, quad core machines can help programmers in unusual ways. I normally program in Prolog so never care about speed, memory usage etc as the problems I solve take humans a week while a machine might take six hours.

This is a hobby, not homework, not work. Something to keep my servers busy rather than warming the planet

Comment: *take a before and after text file and generate and run a program in its-self to produce the after result* `diff`?

Comment: You are 100% correct in your answer. I was looking for something a little more selfaware that might learn to build a rule of transformation from several before and after files. Which I am not sure diff does. Thanks

Comment: one set of before-after is by far too little to learn anything

Comment: "Something to keep my servers busy rather than warming the planet" - a better solution is to let them idle ... or power them off.

Comment: They do spend most of their time down. Only use then when I am testing web pages, server side scripting and database access. They are still only ticking over at 3% load even when I am using them for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of NNs is that the training data can be almost anything. Not sure of an open source project off the top of my head but I'm sure Google would turn up a few dozen.

Comment: Looking for something that will build its own NN or what ever it needs. Wish to become a lazy program and lets the Cores do all the work. Cheers